# Why the type of percentage is translated into decimal type after inputting in R

Tags: r, format

I have a data and there is a percentage column but when I input this dataframe the percentage column was changed into character type and became decimals.

And there are NAs in this column so I don't know how to translate them to percentage type.

Or I also wanna the numeric type.

**My question is why the form is modified, and I'd prefer it not to be changed when it inputs rather than modifying it after it has been entered.(It will be more complex.)**

Here is my sample data:

```
file.f <- structure(list(drug = c("DrugA    ", "DrugB1", "DrugB2", "DrugB3", 
"DrugC1", "DrugC2", "DrugC3", "DrugC4", "DrugA  ", "DrugB1", 
"DrugB2", "DrugB3", "DrugC1", "DrugC2", "DrugC3", "DrugC4"), 
    type = c("P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", 
    "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", 
    "P_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", 
    "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", 
    "G_resistant "), value = c(18, 430, 156, 0, 60, 66, 113, 
    250, 16, 425, 154, 0, 56, 64, 111, 248), group = c(0.8751, 
    0.9885, 0.9871, NA, 0.932, 0.969, 0.982, 0.99, 0.8751, 0.9885, 
    0.9871, NA, 0.932, 0.969, 0.982, 0.99), class = c("Class A ", 
    "Class B", "Class B", "Class B", " Class C", " Class C", 
    " Class C", " Class C", "Class A ", "Class B", "Class B", 
    "Class B", " Class C", " Class C", " Class C", " Class C"
    ), drug_order = c(4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 
    6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")


file.f<-read.xlsx("drug.xlsx")
file.f
```

The orginal data looks like:

[image]

But when it inputs:

[image]

Comment: Could you please include your code to make your question reproducible? Look at [MRE] and [ask] for tips.

Comment: @Peter     Sorry，I forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is not Microsoft Excel, it is a programming language, as such it has a discrete set of data-types it uses natively. Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/r/r_data_types.asp

Additionally, R is what is known as a dynamically typed language -- meaning on import, as well when data is transformed / aggregated, the data-type is resolved by R itself.

That being said you can explicitly type vectors using functions such as: `as.factor()`, `as.character()`, `as.numeric()`, `as.integer()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**I find two simple methods but I don't like it because I need translate it into csv format.**

```
file.csv<-read.csv("drug.csv",sep = ",",header = T)%>%na.omit()
file.csv
##  data.table
library(data.table)
file_data<-fread("drug.csv")%>%na.omit()  ## 可以。
file_data
```

Both of the codes above works well. Is there any other better method?